# Rotational states in higher dimensions: multiple magnetic quantum numbers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, lie-algebra, spacetime-dimensions

In 4 dimensions, arbitrary rotations are usually double rotations (rotations which can be understood as happening independently on two different planes with different rotation angles). It certainly seems like if we take a 4D rigid object (say, a hypercube for simplicity) and apply a series of random torques, then we will find it simultaneously *spinning* on two random orthogonal planes, and the two rotation *rates* will be random and distinct. [In general in $d$ dimensions the rotations can independently happen on $\lfloor d/2 \rfloor$ different planes at the same time.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_of_rotation)

Quantumly, $\hat L_{ij}$ being the angular momentum in the $ij$ plane, we notably have $[\hat L_{ij}, \hat L_{kl}] = 0$ when the $i,j,k,l$ are all distinct axes (the $ij$ and $kl$ planes only intersect at the origin). So, because these certain angular momentum components commute then we can simultaneously diagonalize them, e.g.,
$$\hat L_{12} \psi = \hbar m_{12} \psi$$
$$\hat L_{34} \psi = \hbar m_{34} \psi$$
$$\vdots$$
for the same $\psi$, where $m_{12}$, $m_{34}$, etc. are the magnetic quantum numbers. In general we should be able to have $\lfloor d/2 \rfloor$ simultaneous magnetic quantum numbers, which correspond to that classical spinning at different rates on different planes. (And I guess these also commute with  total angular momentum $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij}\hat L_{ij}^2$ which, as I understand, has eigenvalues of $\hbar^2 l(l+d-2)$.)

My question is, **what can we say about these multiple-magnetic-number eigenstates?** Do $\left| l, m_{12}, m_{34}, \cdots \right>$ give a full basis or are there other mutually commuting quantum operators and quantum numbers? What are the admissible ranges for the magnetic quantum numbers? Are they constrained by a circle inequality like $(m_{12})^2 + (m_{34})^2 + \cdots \leq l(l+d-2)$?

Also it seems the following two kinds of rotational motion are very different, but they ought to get the same angular momentum operator relations and should both be able to have the multiple magnetic quantum numbers:

1. The case of an isotropic rigid rotor like a hypercube (moving in SO($d$) orientation space which is $d(d-1)/2$ dimensional). Even more complicated, the case of an anisotropic moment of inertia is interesting, but perhaps not relevant.
2. The case of a single particle moving in a central potential ($d$ dimensional), which I would assume is related to $d$-dimensional spherical harmonics, but [the information I find](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.3548) about $d$-dimensional spherical harmonics seems to focus on the single-azimuthal-coordinate system.

Comment: As a tangent, it is rather interesting that $d$-dimensional spinors have $2^{\lfloor d/2 \rfloor}$ complex components, just as we'd expect for a higher dimensional 'spin 1/2' where for each of the $\lfloor d/2 \rfloor$ orthogonal planes, the magnetic quantum number can take on one of two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll start by a quick refresher on $\mathfrak{so}(d)$. More generally, the Lie bracket of two basis vectors is:
$$
[L_{ij},L_{kl}]=i(\delta_{ik}L_{jl}+\delta_{jl}L_{ik}-\delta_{il}L_{jk}-\delta_{jk}L_{il})
$$

I will first focus on the case $d=4$. You can notice that $\mathfrak{so}(4)\sim\mathfrak{so}(3)\times\mathfrak{so}(3)$. This is like for the Lorentz group without the tricky sign business. I set for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$:
$$
\begin{align}
L_i &= \epsilon_{ijk}L_{jk} & K_i &= L_{4i} \\
[L_i,L_j] &= \epsilon_{ijk}L_i & [L_i,K_j] &= \epsilon_{ijk}K_i & [K_i,K_j] &= \epsilon_{ijk}L_i  \\
L^+ &= \frac{L+K}2 & L^- &= \frac{L-K}2 \\
[L_i^+,L_j^+] &= \epsilon_{ijk}L_i^+ & [L_i^+,L_j^-] &= 0 & [L_i^-,L_j^-] &= \epsilon_{ijk}L_i^-  \\
\end{align}
$$
Thus, you can label the representations are classified by the eigenvalues of $(L^\pm)^2\to l^\pm(l^\pm+1)$, and the natural analogue of the magnetic quantum number is rather $L^\pm_z\to m^\pm_z$ which must obey:
$$
\begin{align}
|m^\pm_z|\leq l^\pm
\end{align}
$$

It turns out that you may already be familiar with it if you’ve seen the Runge vector of the Kepler problem. For the bound states, you can check that you have an algebra of conserved quantities isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}(4)$ (angular momentum and Runge vector).

Fo the 4D particle in a central potential, the Hamiltonian is:
$$
\begin{align}
H &= \frac{p^2}2+V \\
&= \frac{p_r^2}2+\frac{3p_r}{2r}+\frac{2(L^+)^2+2(L^-)^2}{2r^2}+V
\end{align}
$$
so using the same trick of changing the wave function to revert to a 1D problem with a wall at $r=0$ and effective potential:
$$
V_e = \frac{2l^+(l^++1)+2l^-(l^-+1)}{2r^2}+V
$$

This is not equivalent to the 4D rotator. The distinction is already present in 3D, check out a previous answer of mine on the topic: [Quantum rotator and equipartition theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/718937/333454). You are confusing a particle on a sphere and the isotropic rotator which in appearance have the same Hamiltonian. They have the same spectra, but the degeneracies are different. Furthermore, when the inertia tensor is isotropic, the problem is trivial since you would have conservation of angular momentum in the moving frame as well (the top does not move).

Interesting things happen when the top is anisotropic. A simpler non trivial example would be to assume isotropy in the first three directions. You would have a Hamiltonian of the form:
$$
H = \frac{L^2}{2I_L}+\frac{K^2}{2I_K}
$$

**General dimension**

In general, you’ll need to invoke the full representation theory of $\mathfrak{so}(d)$. Furthermore, you’ll have to distinguish between even and odd $d$. Check out for example *Representation Theory* by Fulton and Harris for specific and general cases.

Apart from the symmetry given by the Weyl group, there is no simple geometric characterization of weight diagram. The rectangular structure  in $d=4$ comes from the reducibility or and the spherical structure that you proposed does not work. The general method is to use the theorem of highest weight and use the root system to figure out the relevant weights.

*Even $d$*

Indeed, $d=4$ is an exception as the Lie algebra is not even simple. It turns out that $\mathfrak{so}(6)$ also presents an accidental isomorphism with $\mathfrak{sl}(4)$, but at least you can visualize the weight diagram in 3D space. The true pattern starts emerging for $d\geq 8$. Already in this case, you can find weight diagrams of intricate geometry.

You indeed have $\frac d2$ magnetic quantum numbers (i.e. the dimension of Cartan subalgebra). You can take $L_{2i,2i+1}$ for the corresponding operators.

*Odd $d$*

The same remark holds. For $d=3$, you have the accidental isomorphism with $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$, and for $d=5$, it is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sp}(4)$. The pattern starts at $d=7$.

You do have $\frac{d-1}2$ magnetic quantum numbers. You can take $L_{2i,2i+1}$ for the corresponding operators.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting, your  $2L_z^+ = L_{12} + L_{43}$ and $2L_z^- = L_{12} - L_{43}$ so your $m_z^{\pm}$ seem to correspond to the left and right isoclinic rotations. Then the $m_{ij}$ I am looking for are $m_{12} = m_z^- + m_z^+$ and $m_{34} = m_z^- - m_z^+$ if I have it right. Okay that is very interesting, that $l^{\pm}$ are the *two* relevant squared angular momenta, and the weird 45° rectangle inequality that they therefore enforce on $m_{12}$ and $m_{34}$. But it seems like this reduction was a special case for 4D; how do we generalize this technique to $\mathfrak{so}(5)$ etc.?

Comment: And that distinction between isotropic rotator and particle on a sphere, thanks! I felt like even in 3D I was already missing something, and felt confused :-) ...

Comment: Also my assumption about eigenvalues of $L^2$ looks to be totally wrong. In fact it appears $L^2 = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij} L_{ij}^2 = 2(L^+)^2 + 2(L^-)^2$ with eigenvalues $2l^+(l^+ + 1) + 2l^-(l^- + 1)$ which are then [0, 4, 4, 8, 12, 12, 16, 16, 24, 24, 24, 28, 28, 36, 36, 40, 40, 44, 44, 48, ...].

Comment: Anyway, thanks. I have more learning to do obviously. I posted a second answer just to show some graphics, but I'll accept this one.

Comment: It occurs to me that I have assumed $m_z^\pm$ must be both integers which leads to $m_{12}$ and $m_{34}$ needing to have the same parity (as seen in the graph in my answer below). But if $m_z^\pm$ were both half-odd-integers then $m_{12}$ and $m_{34}$ could be integers of opposite parity, e.g., we could have $m_{12}=1$ and $m_{34}=0$ and fill the gaps in my example graph. This seems to make sense since SO(3)xSO(3) is actually double covered by SO(4), which is in turn double covered by SU(2)xSU(2).

Comment: OK yes it makes a lot of sense. Including the case where $l^\pm$ are both half-odd, the eigenvalues of rigid body $L^2$ are [0, 3, 4, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16, 19, 24, 25, 28, 33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 44, 48, 49, ...] which thus now fully includes the eigenvalues from spherical harmonics ($l(l+d-2)$) i.e. [0, 3, 8, 15, 24, 35, 48, 63, ...].

Comment: Yes actually to get a representation of $SO(4)$, you’ll need to have both $l^\pm$ to the integers or both half integers. This is how you get the spherical harmonics eigenvalues. If not, it will rather be a representation of the double cover which is not relevant for your applications of a top or a particle in a radial potential. Another way of seeing this is that you want $m_{12},m_{34}$ to be integers, so $2m_z^\pm$ have the same parity.

Comment: The spherical harmonics are obtained when $l^+=l^-$ so that $l=2l^\pm$

Comment: Interesting... the $l^+ = l^- = l/2$ definitely recovers $L^2$ eigenvalues of $l(l+2)$... why does it happen that $l^+ = l^-$ for spherical harmonics though? This feels like it is related to the classical angular momentum for a 4D particle only having 5 dimensions (it is a 2-blade $r \wedge p$, i.e. a simple bivector, so in central potential it has to move in a plane) whereas the full rotator has 6 degrees of freedom (it is a full bivector, can rotate in two planes).

Comment: To make a heuristic argument: if the classical particle motion is only constrained to simple rotations then I guess if we decompose that into the isoclinic rotations, it must be undergoing equal amounts of left and right isoclinic rotation, though not necessarily in the same directions. In other words, $(L^+)^2 = (L^-)^2$. So for spherical harmonics I'd expect $(L^+)^2$ and $(L^-)^2$ operators to be precisely equal, then of course $l^+ = l^-$.

Comment: OK, yeah: $(L^\pm)^2 = \tfrac{1}{4}L^2 \pm L_{12}L_{43} \pm L_{23}L_{41} \pm L_{31}L_{42}$. For the single particle, where $L_{ij} = r_i p_j - r_j p_i$, then $L_{12}L_{43} + L_{23}L_{41} + L_{31}L_{42} = 0$ by substitution. This happens both classical and quantum. So then $(L^+)^2 = (L^-)^2 = \tfrac{1}{4}L^2$ for single particle / spherical harmonics.

Comment: (oops, minor error: actually $(L^\pm)^2 = \tfrac{1}{4}L^2 \pm \tfrac{1}{2}( L_{12}L_{43} + L_{23}L_{41} + L_{31}L_{42})$.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to LPZ's answer, I just want to graphically show the restrictions on the magnetic quantum numbers $m_{12}$ and $m_{34}$ at least in 4 dimensions, to show how wrong my guesses were:

- $m_{12}$ and $m_{34}$ are the sum and difference of two quantum numbers $m_z^+$ and $m_z^-$.
- $m_z^+$ and $m_z^-$ are themselves constrained in magnitude by two azimutal quantum numbers: $|m_z^+| \leq l^+$ and $|m_z^-| \leq l^-$. So this results in a 45-degree rectangle kind of inequality on $m_{12}$ and $m_{34}$, not a circle.
- $l^+$ and $l^-$ may be both integers or both half-odd integers. In the first case, then $m_{12}$ and $m_{34}$ must have same parity (both odd or both even); in the latter case, they have opposite parity.
- The eigenvalues of $L^2$ are $2\hbar^2[l^+(l^+ + 1) + l^-(l^- + 1)]$.

So given $l^+$ and $l^-$, the map of admissible $m_{12}$ and $m_{34}$ numbers looks something like this: (dots are admitted values, and the dashed circles show the $L^2$ circle boundary)

[image: plot of admissible values of m numbers]

Going beyond 4 dimensions, I still don't know what to expect.

For fun, here is an animation I made of a 5-cell spinning classically in 4D, doubly rotating in the $xy$ and $wz$ planes. The $wz$ plane angular velocity is 75% that of the $xy$ plane. [More info on wikimedia commons.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Double_4D_rotation_of_a_5-cell.webm)

[image: animation of rotating]